# HTTP Basic Authentication and Attlassian JIRA, Confluence and Bitbucekt

Tags: apache, security, jira, reverse-proxy, confluence

I have JIRA, Confluence and Bitbucket deployed on my server behind Apache reverse proxy. Each of them is connected with others using Application links. Now, I want to add additional layer of protection by implementing HTTP Basic Authentication in front of this. When I do this, I lose connection between apps. How to configure Apache properly in order to have HTTP Basic Authentication in front of whole stack AND connection between apps?

Comment: Have you tried the `http://user:pass@jira.example.com` syntax in the application link config?

Answer (score 0):

Where did you configure basic authentication?

Normally Atlassian applications handle authentication themselves, so you should not have to configure anything in apache.

Application links use OAuth to handle authentication between applications and there are 2 flavors:

- if both applications have the same set of users, you can use plain OAuth
- if both applications have a different set of users, you can use OAuth with impersonation

More info is available in the [Application Links documentation here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver071/using-applinks-to-link-to-other-applications-802592232.html).