# Jira / Bitbucket Application Links with Basic Authentication

Tags: authentication, bitbucket, jira, basic-authentication

This is admittedly a duplicate of this question :
[HTTP Basic Authentication and Attlassian JIRA, Confluence and Bitbucekt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44753878/http-basic-authentication-and-attlassian-jira-confluence-and-bitbucekt)

... but I have the same question, and that was not answered!

Does anyone know how to setup "Application Links" between Jira, Bitbucket, or other Atlassian apps when the remote app requires basic authentication?  The legacy docs for Jira indicate there use to be a basic authentication option, but they seem to have eliminated that.

Comment: As an update to this, I was thinking about it, and I might have an additional problem if I try this which is trying to push/pull across the git repo.  If I put basic authentication in front of my bitbucket url, will I kill the ability to push/pull, or will various local git utilities perhaps be able to handle this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with a combination of very old and new applications, then it is possible that you cannot create an application link between them, unless you upgrade your legacy application(s).

Atlassian has this in their Application Links documentation:

> As a general rule, you should ensure your applications are using the same major version of AppLinks to resolve any potential incompatibilities.

[For a matrix of compatible versions, look here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/applinks/application-links-version-matrix-779174762.html).

Comment: Thank you Glenn.  I'm using the newest version available for download of both Jira and Bitbucket.  They link perfectly fine under normal circumstances.  My problem is created when I put them behind a reverse proxy, then add basic authentication to that proxy.  I've seen some docs for specifying basic auth parameters to the Tomcat configurations, but that seems to be for fixing a "reflective" complication. I don't need that. I fixed that apparent issue on the proxy side. I need to pass outbound parms instead to this link, else the first layer of auth can't be passed through.